# Probability of choosing an item from set and set iteslf

Tags: probability, combinations

I hvae a question

Two cards are drawn from a pack of well shuffled cards. Find the probability that one is a club and other in King.

Solving. 
We split them into two parts
1- If a king is from the club then probability

1/52 (Probability that club king is choosen) * 12 /51 ( probability that club is choosen )

1/52 * 12/51

2- If kings are taken other than club
3/52  * 13/51

Now P(A) + P(B) = 
This gives  1 /52

However the answer is half of this 1/26, what wrong i did here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to multiply your result by  2 because the order in which you draw the cards doesn't matter.

Here you only computed the probability if you **have to** draw the king first.